# TabHost activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, tabs

I have a beach layout of 12 beaches.
And i want to add each of them a tabhost with two tabs one info (this is default) and the other map.
I have create two activities for each of the two info and map and one third to put together this two? I have to do and for the other 11 beaches?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of data you have, but that would requre a total of 37 activities (1 "main" activity, and 3 activities for each beach).  That's way, way too complicated.

Instead, drop all your beach data into a database.  Then when you select a beach to view information on, move the user to the two-tab view, and have those tabs pull the map & info data for the specific beach from the database.

FYI, you probably don't need full activities for each of the two tabs:  Giving each tab a View instead would be more lightweight, unless there's a specific reason you need activities in them.

Comment: No i put only some info about the beach and at map tab where is located. so i beleive your way is better how i can add info data for all my beaches and how i drop them?

Comment: Here's some info from the developer site about data storage:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: How can i have as i say before 3 activities info, map and beachifo which beachinfo have two tabhost info and map? And when i select one of 12 beaches drop data and saw them. Or is better to make these three activities for each of 12 beaches????

Comment: I try to tell better because my english is not so good. I try to make a app about beaches in an island. My main activity is a scrollview activity with 12 button each of this has a unique name of a beach. I want when i select one of these 12 to get a new activity with two tabhost one info which must be default and one map which must saw in the map where is the beach. When i asked before someone tell me to create a data base an drop data. First How can i make database??? second how can i get the result for each beach?